# Cannot able to fill out the HTML form in iPhone the text are not visible properly

Tags: html, iphone, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a website built using bootstrap, contact form 7 and wordpress. It has a form and the text are not visible in iPhone or in Mobile responsive mode. Plz check the url diamovitcarhire .com.

```
* { 
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
*:not(input.field) {    
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
input, textarea {
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif ! ;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);   
    font-size:large !important;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Why the images are not clear in mobile view http://i63.tinypic.com/296hoxf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you're using Contact Form 7 you need to unformatted html code. Formatted contact form may create unnecessary para and line break tags.

Do something like this

```
<div class="formsearch"> <div id="availabilityform"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="Car">Vehicle Preference</label> [select* Car id:Car class:form-control class:input-md "Range Rover Sport HSE" "Range Rover Vogue" "Range Rover Evoque" "Porsche Cayenne S" "Mercedes-Benz ML" "Audi Q7" "BMW X6" "BMW X5" "Porsche Cayenne Turbo" "Hummer" "Lamborgini Gallardo Spyder" "Bentley GTC" "Ferrari 458 Italia Spyder" "Ferrari California" "Audi R8 V10 Spyder" "Aston Martin" "Ferrari 430 Spyder" "Porsche 911 Turbo Cabrio" "Porsche 911 Carrera S Cabrio" "Jaguar XKR Cabrio" "Maserati Gran Cabrio" "Mercedes Benz E350 AMG Cabrio" "Mercedes-Benz S class Long" "Mercedes-Benz C class" "Mercedes-Benz SLS AMG" "Bentley Continental GT" "Porsche Panamera Turbo"] </div></div></div><div class="row" id="sandbox-container"> <div class="col-md-6" > <div class="form-group"> <label for="StartDate">Start Date </label> [date* StartDate id:StartDate class:form-control date-format:mm/dd/yy min-date:mm/dd/yy max-date:mm/dd/yy]</div></div><div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="endDate ">End Date </label> [date* endDate id:endDate class:form-control date-format:mm/dd/yy min-date:mm/dd/yy max-date:mm/dd/yy]</div></div></div><div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6" > <div class="form-group"> <label for="Name">Name</label> [text* Name class:form-control] </div></div><div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="phone">Phone </label> [text* Phone class:form-control] </div></div></div><div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="Email">Email </label> [email* Email class:form-control] </div></div></div><div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="Comments">Comments </label> [textarea Comments class:form-control] </div></div></div><div class="c12"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="fps_value">[submit id:submit_vehicle_search class:frontfancybox "Inquiry"]</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>` tag inside the form-group and check. It worked for me. And to add more point code should be cleaned up.

- Remove empty empty `<p>` tags. Its is costly operation to add DOM just for sake of margin. Instead give margin to span 0r form-group class.

Comment: Please do let me know why the texts are not clear in mobile view http://i63.tinypic.com/296hoxf.png